# What skills are Drow proficient in?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, proficiency, drow

I've been trying to find out what skills Drow have options to be proficient in, typically a race offers a few choices but only allows you to pick two, and your class gives you two more, followed by your background giving you 1 or 2 more correct? But I've looked at numerous sites trying to find out what skill choices Drow offer and have found none. Is it an error or do they really have no skill proficiencies? I know they have some weapon proficiencies and whatnot but I figured they'd have some skills too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The Drow race does not confer any skill proficiency

I looked up my [PHB on page 24](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/elf#DarkElfDrow), and the only proficiencies gained by Drow are rapiers, shortswords, and hand crossbows, in addition to Perception given by being an Elf (of any kind).

### Most races do not confer skill proficiencies, and no option of selecting among them

Some races give proficiency in certain tools (like Rock Gnomes), or armor (like Mountain Dwarves), or even skills (like Elves), but it is not an automatic thing every race does.

The only races that I've seen that give a choice of skills are Half-Elf which has Skill Versatility, you gain proficiency in two skills of your choice,
and a variant trait for Human, which gives 1 skill of your choice.

### Classes let you choose (usually 2) skills to be proficient in

Based on your class you can choose a number of skills to be proficient in, from a provided list. You may be confusing this with what you get from your race.

Backgrounds also give 2 skill proficiencies, but these are determined by the background you choose and can't be mixed or changed (although you can make a custom background to choose the skills you want).

Comment: Covered the background thing  in the edit.

Comment: There are some more races that give skill proficiencies outside the PHB, such as Kenku, Lizardfolk and Tabaxi from VGtM, and Githyanki from MToF

Comment: @Jorn That's mostly why I had tried to avoid that statement, but the general theme remains correct :)

Comment: Variant Human also gets 1 skill proficiency of choice.

Answer (score 8):

[Drow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/elf#DarkElfDrow) get the following:

Being an Elf gives them the following Skill proficiency (PHB, 23):

> **Keen Senses**
>
> You have proficiency in the Perception skill.

And being Drow gives you the following weapon proficiencies (PHB, 24):

> **Drow Weapon Training**
>
> You have proficiency with rapiers, shortswords, and hand crossbows.

Because there other benefits for being Elf and Drow-Elf, no other skill profiencies are provided.

### Skills generally come from Class and Background

Each **[Class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/classes#ClassesSummary)** will give you an option to select Skills. These are listed under the **Class Features** section and will list what skills are available and how many you can choose.

Each **[Background](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Backgrounds)** will also give you skill choices, and you can always choose to do a [custom background](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/personality-and-background#CustomizingaBackground), allowing you greater freedom in skills/proficiencies/languages.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer, but I really think you should correct the misconceptions in the question.

Comment: @Miniman Yeah, i wasn't sure on how to handle that because some races do get skills, and one does get a choice. So it seemed better to just answer the specific ask about drow skills than try and provide a broader direction, although [GreySage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/137531/23024) has done a good job that. But i'll try and add a bit.

Comment: @Miniman how's that?